# How do I iterate over a Map<Integer, Set>?

Tags: java

So if i have the following:

```
TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> returnMap = new TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>>();
```

How do I create an iterator for the treeset inside of the map?
I tried the following:

```
Iterator<String> mapItr = returnMap.values();
```

Comment: `Iterator<TreeSet<String>> mapItr`.

Comment: My iterator is being passed to another method, and has to have the Iterator<String> not Iterator<TreeSet<String>>

Comment: Well, convert it somehow, for example by adding everything in the iterator of sets into a list of strings, and then pass the iterator of that list into the method. Or use something like `Iterables.concat` from Guava.

Comment: There is not a single `TreeSet`, there is one `TreeSet` for each distinct key value.  Are you wanting to iterate over one of those `TreeSet`s or _all of them combined_?  Please clarify.  If the latter, do you care about the iteration order?

Comment: `returnMap.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).forEach(...)`

Comment: Instead of an `Iterator<String>`, I suggest having a `Stream<String>` as it's simpler and faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about order...

```
final TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> returnMap = new TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>>();

final List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
for (final TreeSet<String> treeSet : returnMap.values()) {
  strings.addAll(treeSet);
}

final Iterator<String> mapItr = strings.iterator();
```

In Java 8, using streams, it could be:

```
final Iterator<String> mapItr = returnMap
                                  .values()
                                  .stream()
                                  .flatMap(Set::stream)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                  .iterator();
```

If you do care about order, you will need to go through your `TreeSet` instances in whatever order you want.

Comment: Up-voted, but I wonder what you mean by *"don't care about order"*, given that the order of first code fragment is very well-defined, i.e. primarily ordered by `Integer` key, secondarily ordered by `String` value. Second code fragment would have equally well-defined order if you change to `toList()`, which you should do anyway, since you're currently removing duplicate values.

Comment: @Andreas What I meant about not caring is perhaps he wanted to iterate in an order that is not just ascending based on the key. Perhaps descending, or even numbers first. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯